# i2c access from kernel

Tags: kernel, i2c

In userspace we can access any bus very simple, but from kernel it seems very complex doing simple access. the first argument to i2c_transfer is pointer to struct i2c_adapter, which is very complex struct to fill.

Isn't there a simpler way to access a bus (for example i2c-2) from kernel?

If I know bus number what should I put in i2c_adapter ?

Thanks, Ran

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, their is a solution, though not so easy to be found without help.

i2c_get_adapter(bus_number);

I hope it helps for anyone who gets into the same issue of building some driver such as character device which needs to use i2c.

Regards, Ran